# Display richtext on webview with smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I tried to run [Webview richtext display](https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/webview/)    with below code given in the referance document but it gives empty page.
Did something wrong on the code or just does not support webview rich text?

```
Pages.Page1.webView1 = new SMF.UI.WebView({
    top : "5%",
    left : "5%",
    width : "90%",
    height : "90%",
    URL : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
});
Pages.Page1.add(Pages.Page1.webView1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign your rich text as HTML to the URL to display a rich text paragraph in a Webview.You can add as below:

```
Pages.Page1.webView1 = new SMF.UI.WebView({
        top : "5%",
        left : "5%",
        width : "90%",
        height : "90%",
        URL : "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit.</strong><mark>Nummus in Croesi divitiis obscuratur,</mark> pars est tamen divitiarum. Utrum igitur tibi litteram videor an totas paginas commovere?</p>"
    });
Pages.Page1.add(Pages.Page1.webView1);
```